# Difficulty with MPI_Bcast: how to ensure that "correct" root is broadcasting

Tags: c++, c, mpi

I am relatively new to MPI (with C), and am having some trouble using MPI_Bcast to send an int to all processes.

In my code, I decide which rank is root within a for loop, where different processes are responsible for different element of the loop. Then, I want to Bcast a result from root to all processes, except all non-root processes do not know who to expect the bcast from, so do not receive it.

The code block looks something like this:

```
for (iX=start; iX<end; iX++)
//start and end are the starting row and ending row for each processes, defined earlier

  for (int iY=1; iY<nn; iY++)

    // do some calculations

    if (some condition)

      int bcastroot = rank;  // initialized above
      int X = 111;   // initialized above

    else
      //do other calculations

  end
end

MPI_Bcast(&X, 1, MPI_INT, bcastroot, comm);

// remainder of code and MPI_FINALIZE
```

When I execute this code, whatever the bcastroot default (value for all non-root processes) competes with root, so X is not broadcast correctly. I do not know the value of X nor can I predict the root beforehand, so I cannot define it in advance.

I have tried initializing bcastroot = -1, then setting it for rank, but this does not work. Is there a way I can Bcast this value without setting root for all processes?

Thanks,
JonZor

Comment: If you do not know the root, you need to communicate it. Maybe bcast is not the right choice here? Did you have a look into MPI_Allreduce if it could solve your problem?

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to do an `MPI_Bcast` where the receivers don't know what the root is.  If you know there will only be one root, you can first do an `MPI_Allreduce` to agree on it:

```
int root, maybe_root;
int i_am_root = ...;
maybe_root = (i_am_root ? rank : 0);
MPI_Allreduce(&maybe_root, &root, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_MAX, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

then every rank will know the same root and you can do your broadcast.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremiah, much appreciated. That works great! I actually was just starting to come up with that same solution just before I read your response.